# Audio AutoPlay on HTML Website not working

Tags: html, html5-video

I tried to make a fan-website for a artist so I wanted to have start page music which automatically plays. But, when I open the start page, my audio file doesn't play.

This is my code:

```html
<audio controls autoplay loop>
   <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/bigger-picture.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <p>If you can read this, your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>
```

What I need to do to make this start playing automatically?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: are u testing this website on phone?

Comment: @GautamNaik , 
No, I test on PC, on Google Chrome and autoplay don't work.

Comment: Auto playing anything is generally a bad idea as it is very annoying, however, putting that aside....it probably hasn't loaded the file yet.

Comment: Are you attempting to do this on an iOS device? Because Apple specifically prevent auto-playing audio (or video with an audio track) unless the user changes the default browser settings.

Comment: [https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/bigger-picture.mp3](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Syntaxxx/bigger-picture.mp3) This mp3 file can not visit?

Answer (score 2):

autoplay is a html standard. It's up to then browser to support it or not. I suspect you used Chrome, like so many others, and were surprised it didn't work.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp
If you test this code, like I did, in Firefox 63, it will work fine.
Google decided to break the web standard in May 2018:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=840866#c103

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020, browser defaults mean this won't work in Firefox (all platforms) and Chrome (Android included, but not Mac it seems).

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your browser's [here Firefox]
Autoplay preferences (blocked or not) in
about:preferences#privacy