# How can I make my embeded YouTube video Autoplay on my html static website?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, autoplay

I am trying to have auto-playing background music on my personal website but am having some difficulty given the autoplay policy of most browsers. I have tried making a subpage so that then a user has to interact with the site and thus warrant autoplay per the policies but I can't seem to get anything to work.

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Audio AutoPlay on HTML Website not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201454/audio-autoplay-on-html-website-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Videos need to be muted to autoplay due to browser restrictions. Easiest way to do this is to add `autoplay=1&mute=1` at the end of your YouTube URL.

So it would be like: `youtube.com/embed/ejSjr49E?autoplay=1&mute=1`

Answer (score 1):

The thing with auto playing audio is, that it tends to be widely misused by online advertisement, etc. You can use a library like [howler.js](https://howlerjs.com/) thou, they try to silently unlock the player on the first touch event: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#mobilechrome-playback

From the documentation:

> If you try to play audio automatically on page load, you can listen to a playerror event and then wait for the unlock event to try and play the audio again:
>
> ```
> var sound = new Howl({
>    src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3'],
>    onplayerror: function() {
>      sound.once('unlock', function() {
>          sound.play();
>      });
>    }
>  });
>    
>  sound.play();
> ```

I would say this is your best shot, but there is no guarantee.